# How do I setup jmeter to make POST request with bearer token, api key and other parameters?

Tags: json, post, jmeter, postman, http-post

Can someone please show me how to make POST request in jmeter if I have a bearer token, x-api key, api url, and json body in this format:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "08b4-4ee4-b51b-803e20ae8126",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Player",
        "name": [
          {
            "family": "Jameson",
            "given": [
              "Matt"
            ]
          }
        ],
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Player"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also how do I setup parameters as shown in image:
Image below shows how I set it up in postman, all parameters
https://ibb.co/C8dwQ2m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your Test Plan and put the URL and the JSON payload there

   [image]
2. All the values which are at your screenshot stand for [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) so add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and specify the values there:

   [image]